# SQL statement to return a count of two columns

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm using SQL inside of Excel VBA. I am trying to get a count of [Diagrams] and [FinDate] for distinct [Packets].

In the data table the [Packets] column will have duplicated packets. I need to count how many [Diagrams] and [FinDate] exist for each packet.

Data Table:

```
| Diagrams | Packets  | FinDate  |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 1526     |    525   | 04/12/23 |
| 1837     |    525   | 04/25/23 |
| 4-b-85   |    525   | 03/18/23 |
| a-468    |    503   | 05/06/23 |
| 3857     |    580   | 04/03/23 |
| b-d3d    |    580   |          |
| void     |    580   | 03/29/23 |
| c-854    |    503   | 05/01/23 |
| 0        |    525   |          |
```

Desired SQL Output:

```
| Packets  | Diagrams | FinDate  |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 503      |      2   |      2   |
| 525      |      4   |      3   |
| 580      |      3   |      2   |
```

This is sql statement works if I'm trying to count one column, but when I insert the second count criteria it breaks.

```vb
Sub CountOfDiagrams_FinDate()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
  & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "SELECT [Packets], " & _
         "COUNT([Diagrams]) AS AMOUNT, COUNT([FinDate]) AS AMOUNT " & _
         "FROM [MECHANICAL$] " & _
         "GROUP BY [Packets]"

rs.Open strSQL, cn

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

' row
Dim r As Integer
r = 2
' column
Dim c As Integer
c = 1

Cells(r, c).CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
cn.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Why have both counts called AMOUNT ?

Comment: Because they both need to be the amount of non-zero occurrences for their respective columns. If you notice in the desired output sometimes the FinDate will not have the same count as the diagrams. It's actually the main purpose of the query, to find the discrepancies in my data table. Not to say that they both should be written as an amount, I'm still new to sql and learning.

Comment: Try using different names in the SQL like AS AMOUNT1  , AS AMOUNT2

Comment: That worked, thank you very much. If you don't mind, could you tell me why it worked? And how do I give you credit with the green check mark?